# Combine 3 Queries into One, Using Joins or Nested Queries?

Tags: mysql, jira

I have 3 different queries that are displaying the same data, but for different date intervals. I am not sure of the best way to combine the queries to show all of the data in one. I am not great at joins or nested queries, so I am unsure of the best way to so this.

Basically I want to have 4 columns: Associate, 30 Days, 60 Days, and 90 Days.

Query 1:

```
SELECT cwd_user.display_name AS 'Associate', sum(worklog.timeworked/3600) AS '30 Days'
FROM worklog, cwd_user,cwd_membership
WHERE worklog.AUTHOR = cwd_user.user_name
and cwd_user.directory_id = cwd_membership.directory_id
and cwd_user.lower_user_name = cwd_membership.lower_child_name
and cwd_membership.membership_type = 'GROUP_USER'
and cwd_membership.lower_parent_name = 'atl_servicedesk_it_agents'
and worklog.STARTDATE BETWEEN NOW() AND DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 DAY)
GROUP BY cwd_user. display_name
ORDER BY cwd_user.last_name;
```

Query 2:

```
SELECT cwd_user.display_name AS 'Associate', sum(worklog.timeworked/3600) AS '60 Days'
FROM worklog, cwd_user,cwd_membership
WHERE worklog.AUTHOR = cwd_user.user_name
and cwd_user.directory_id = cwd_membership.directory_id
and cwd_user.lower_user_name = cwd_membership.lower_child_name
and cwd_membership.membership_type = 'GROUP_USER'
and cwd_membership.lower_parent_name = 'atl_servicedesk_it_agents'
and worklog.STARTDATE BETWEEN NOW() AND DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 60 DAY)
GROUP BY cwd_user. display_name
ORDER BY cwd_user.last_name;
```

Query 3:

```
SELECT cwd_user.display_name AS 'Associate', sum(worklog.timeworked/3600) AS '90 Days'
FROM worklog, cwd_user,cwd_membership
WHERE worklog.AUTHOR = cwd_user.user_name
and cwd_user.directory_id = cwd_membership.directory_id
and cwd_user.lower_user_name = cwd_membership.lower_child_name
and cwd_membership.membership_type = 'GROUP_USER'
and cwd_membership.lower_parent_name = 'atl_servicedesk_it_agents'
and worklog.STARTDATE BETWEEN NOW() AND DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 90 DAY)
GROUP BY cwd_user. display_name
ORDER BY cwd_user.last_name;
```

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Untested... because there was nothing to test it on...

```
SELECT u.display_name Associate
     , SUM(CASE WHEN w.startdate BETWEEN NOW() AND NOW() + INTERVAL 30 DAY THEN w.timeworked END/3600) '30 Days'
     , SUM(CASE WHEN w.startdate BETWEEN NOW() AND NOW() + INTERVAL 60 DAY THEN w.timeworked END/3600) '60 Days'
     , SUM(CASE WHEN w.startdate BETWEEN NOW() AND NOW() + INTERVAL 90 DAY THEN w.timeworked END/3600) '90 Days'
  FROM worklog w
  JOIN cwd_user u
    ON u.user_name = w.author 
  JOIN cwd_membership m
    ON m.directory_id = u.directory_id
   AND m.lower_child_name = u.lower_user_name
 WHERE m.membership_type = 'GROUP_USER'
   AND m.lower_parent_name = 'atl_servicedesk_it_agents'
   AND w.startdate BETWEEN NOW() AND DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 90 DAY)
 GROUP 
    BY u. display_name
 ORDER 
    BY u.last_name;
```

Comment: That worked! You are amazing! I didn't realize I could do it like that, but I will definitely use that in the future!